# Shared Preferences use on Change color RaisedButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two `RaisedButton` that you can click only one of them. After clicking one, can't work other one or deselect your choice. Buttons change color when clicked. One is green and the other one is red. Like correct and wrong. (The example in the image is only for green. On the right that can turn red.)

[image]

There is no problem with their work.

I want to save the user's choice with `shared_preferences` for **only green color**.

I guess what I wrote or place I used is wrong. Like here:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getGreen();
  }

  Future<bool> saveGreen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool ('answerGreen', true);
  }

  Future<bool> getGreen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return _correct = prefs.getBool("answerGreen");
  }
...
...
 onPressed: () => {
                  setState(() {
                    _correct = !_wrong;
                    saveGreen();
                  })
                },
```

**If the user chose green, I want green to show when the user turns the app restart. How can i do this with `shared_preferences` ?**

(I don't think it makes any difference to save green or red. Or both. I can not save the problem)

Full code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ButtonChangeColor(),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonChangeColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonChangeColorState createState() => _ButtonChangeColorState();
}

class _ButtonChangeColorState extends State<ButtonChangeColor> {
  bool _correct = false;
  bool _wrong = false;

  /*
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getGreen();
  }

  Future<bool> saveGreen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool ('answerGreen', true);
  }

  Future<bool> getGreen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return _correct = prefs.getBool("answerGreen");
  }
  */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Change Color'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: _correct ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () => {
                  setState(() {
                    _correct = !_wrong;
                    //saveGreen();  //??
                  })
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Change Color'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: _wrong ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () => {
                  setState(() {
                    _wrong = !_correct;
                  })
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use Elevated button instead of RaisedButton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please you can try this, I have code edited and please tell me if this code perfect?

```
class ButtonChangeColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonChangeColorState createState() => _ButtonChangeColorState();
}

class _ButtonChangeColorState extends State<ButtonChangeColor> {
  bool _correct = false;
  bool _wrong = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getGreen();
    getRed();
  }

  Future<bool> saveGreen(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('answerGreen', value);
  }

  Future<bool> getGreen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _correct = prefs.getBool("answerGreen");
if(_correct==null){
_correct=false;
}
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<bool> saveRed(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('answerRed', value);
  }

  Future<bool> getRed() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _wrong = prefs.getBool("answerRed");
if(_wrong == null){
_wrong= false;
}
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Change Color'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: _correct ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () => {
                  setState(() {
                    // _correct = !_wrong;
                    _correct = true;
                    _wrong = false;
                    saveGreen(true);
                    saveRed(false);
                    //saveGreen();  //??
                  })
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Change Color'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: _wrong ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () => {
                  setState(() {
                    _correct = false;
                    _wrong = true;
                    saveGreen(false);
                    saveRed(true);
                  })
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use ElevatedButton because RaisedButton has been deprected.

Comment: @Hars Chovatiya  When I use your code, I get an error `boolean expression must not be null`  [like here](https://ibb.co/rG8fcRj)

Comment: @zeed Please now check this I have editing  code in my existing code

Comment: Although the requirement to click only once is not provided, my main problem: save has been resolved. Thanks. Using `_correct = !_wrong` and `_wrong = !_correct` , I provide the condition to make a selection once. But `onPressed` keep working, `saveColor` method works and changes save value. (It can save red while showing green. If the first green is clicked and after red is clicked.) I understood that it is a different question subject. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should separate buttons and do only specific actions in `onPressed`:

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Change Color'),
  textColor: Colors.white,
  color: _correct ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
  onPressed: () => {
    setState(() {
      _correct = !_wrong;
      _wrong = !_correct;
      if (_correct) {
        saveGreen();
      }
    })
  },
),
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Change Color'),
  textColor: Colors.white,
  color: _wrong ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
  onPressed: () => {
    setState(() {
      _wrong = !_correct;
      _correct = !_wrong;
    })
  },
)
```

Comment: Use ElevatedButton instead of RaisedButton